# Need help in social engine signup process

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm new to social engine. I have created the four member type and profile type. I have a mapping of member type and profile type. I want to select member type and it will be automatically assigned a profile type. My script is here.

```
 <?php 
      echo ($this->header_signupbutton == 0) ? 
           'javascript:void(0)' : 
           $this->url(array('module'=>'','controller' => '','action'=>'signup'), 'default', true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use this plugin. You can do with the socialengine after signup hook where you can get the viewer detail and can update the member level.

Comment: `this plugin` which plugin?

Comment: I need solution of this topic.

Comment: please check this link http://www.socialengine.com/customize/se4/mod-page?mod_id=247

Comment: i cannot download that plugin